# Why is the popstate event handler not working?

Tags: javascript, events, safari, event-handling, popstate

I have registered the popstate event as a listener in JS, but only in Safari on My Mac it does not fire when the back button is pressed; in Chrome and Firefox it fires.

My Safari version is 16.3 (18614.4.6.1.5).

Here is the code

```
            window.history.pushState(null, null, null);

            window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
                console.log('fire!')
            });
```

How can I get back button event detection in Safari?

Comment: i guess because of in pushstate everything is null. add popstate event in another page . then navigate from one page to another page (popstate event)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I added '#back' to the third argument of pushState to check the behavior, but the behavior did not change.